# Jest/Storyshots test responsive elements in my components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, storybook, storyshots

I am using react material ui combined with storybook and storyshots. I am trying to understand how I can test responsive elements in material-ui with jest or storyshots via storybook

I have `Hidden` elements in my components like the following

```
<Hidden xsDown>
    {displayText}
</Hidden>
```

and stories that look roughly like

```
storiesOf("Card", module)
    .addDecorator(muiTheme(myTheme))
    .add("options bar", () => (
        <Card {...someProps}/>
    ));
```

I have tried modding the breakpoints in my theme, which has an effect when viewing through storybook. However no matter what I have tried, the `Hidden` element never renders in my snapshots.

I have also tried not using the `Hidden` element and tried `className` styles to set `display: none` if `theme.breakpoints.down('xs')` is true. This produces the element in my snapshot like

```
<h6
   className="MuiTypography-root CardOptions-label-1170 MuiTypography- 
 subtitle2"
>
   View Route
</h6>
```

but nothing in this block tells me that the element is being hidden on `xs` screens.

It seem like I should be able to somehow toggle `xsDown` in the `Hidden` element to be true or false in storybook to have storyshot render or not render the element in my snapshot, but I am having no luck figuring that out.

I guess in general I am just wondering how most people are testing responsive UIs with jest. It seems like I should be able to accomplish this with snapshots but maybe I am missing something.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Storybook does not provide a responsive UI testing library out of the box.

However, you can use an additional library such as [Chroma](https://hichroma.com/) (company behind Storybook) or [React screenshot test](https://github.com/fwouts/react-screenshot-test).

Which one you choose really depends on other factors.

Read more on Chroma: https://blog.hichroma.com/responsive-ui-component-testing-6d38b7e89dd4